# How could I call 2 functions with only one data-bind?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to make 2 functions run into only one data-bind, but I'm facing some problems because one of this functions is running inside the HTML and I can't change this. I have google this question and get that:

```
click:function(key){text: text}, click:callFunction()
```

But this isn't working. The second click bind is working, but the first one no.

Here's my button:

```
<button data-bind="attr: {for: 'CC-prodDetails-' + $data.value}, text:key, 
                                                click:function(key){
                                                    $parent.selectedOption(key);
                                                    $parent.selectedOptionValue(key);
                                                }" class="volt"></button>
```

Here's the function that I need to run:

```
            changeClass: function () {
            $("button.volt").toggleClass('voltActive');
        },
```

Someone could help me?
Put the HTML function inside the other or change it to JS isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can call both an HTML function and an JS function by wrapping the JS function in the HTML function. The first parameter supplied to the HTML function is the current bound model:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  myJsFunction: function() { console.log('JS function called'); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: function(model) { console.log('HTML function called'); model.myJsFunction(); }">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I changed the code so I won't need to use a double function call anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use the `css` binding?

```
<button data-bind="
    attr: { for: 'CC-prodDetails-' + $data.value },
    text: key, 
    click: function (key) {
        $parent.selectedOption(key);
        $parent.selectedOptionValue(key);
    },
    css: {
        'voltActive': $parent.selectedOption() === key,
        'volt': $parent.selectedOption() !== key
    }"></button>
```

Or the `class` binding that was introduced in 3.5:

```
class: $parent.selectedOption() === key ? 'voltActive': 'volt'
```

Comment: I don't know neither of this two options. I'll try it and see the result.
Maybe a problem will be that I need that one of this buttons is already 'selected', so I'm using this onLoad:
`$(function() {
                    $('button.volt').first().addClass('voltActive');
                });`

Comment: Aren't working now, but I'm trying to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I changed the code so I won't need to use a double function call anymore.